# Were there any intra-EU concerns expressed that Germany was practicing dumping prices on aluminium sheets?

Tags: united-states, european-union, trade, germany, greece

Reuters [reports](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-trade-aluminum/u-s-commerce-sets-anti-dumping-duties-on-aluminum-sheet-from-18-countries-idUSKCN2AU2S4?il=0) on the new anti-dumping duties imposed by the Biden administration on aluminium sheets (worldwide):

> The U.S. Commerce Department on Tuesday issued final anti-dumping duties on common alloy aluminum sheet from 18 countries investigated, including up to 242.8% on imports from Germany and 4.83% on imports from Bahrain.
>
> The duties were announced just hours after Rhode Island Governor Gina Raimondo won confirmation as the new U.S. Commerce Secretary in an 84-15 U.S. Senate vote.
>
> The anti-dumping case and a companion anti-subsidy countervailing duty case were initiated under the Trump administration in March 2020.
>
> Germany had the highest anti-dumping rate, ranging from 49.4% to 242.8%, and the largest exports of aluminum sheet to the United States, with $286.6 million worth in 2019.
>
> The duties will come on top of 10% U.S. tariffs imposed on most aluminum imports by the Trump administration under a national security law.

From the more detailed US [schedule](https://www.trade.gov/faq/final-determinations-antidumping-and-countervailing-duty-investigations-common-alloy-aluminum), [unless there's some typo] Greece was only hit with 2.72% anti-dumping duties (actually less than Bahrain). So if Germany was dumping so much in comparison to Greece, in terms of pricing (as the US says), were there any intra-EU concerns expressed that Germany was  practicing dumping prices on aluminium sheets?

Comment: Dumping is not really a concern (anymore?) within the EU, state aid would be. There are a few procedures (one regarding a Greek company and one on the [German renewable energy act](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/eli/dec/2015/1585/oj)) but nothing dramatic. Note that the duties are not imposed on a country but on specific exporters. It would be useful to know what the rate is based on and how the US definition of dumping aligns with EU law.